# Equation for exponential deceleration so the objects “stops” at destination

Tags: exponential-function, kinematics

Let's say my ship's velocity during deceleration phase is given by:

```
v(t) = v0 * exp(-k * t)
```

where `v0` is the speed at the time of starting deceleration and `k` is arbitrary constant.

My problem is: Is it possible to calculate such k that the ship "stops" (let's say slows to a velocity `vf`) at the target position given:

- `v0`
- distance to the target `d0` ?

Or alternatively: given k calculating a distance at which deacceleration should start?

I'm making a space simulation game where the ship's warp drive needs to accelerate/decelerate exponentially. While accelerating to a maximum speed is easy the problem is with decelerating so that the ship "stops" at the destination.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total distance travelled on stopping would be

$$
d_{0} = v_{0}\int_{0}^{t_{f}}e^{-kt}dt
$$

Which evaluates to

$$
d_{0} = \frac{v_{0}}{k}(1 - e^{-kt_{f}})
$$

We also have

$$
v_{f} = v_{0}e^{-kt_{f}}
$$

So we can plug in $ln(\frac{v_{f}}{v_{0}})$ for -$kt_{f}$ in the original equation to get

$$
d_{0} = \frac{v_{0}}{k}(1 - \frac{v_{f}}{v_{0}})
$$

or

$$
k = \frac{v_{0} - v_{f}}{d_{0}}
$$